# Auth violation while using a CakePHP plugin model inside a different plugin's controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using a UsersController and trying to access a method on that model in another plugins controller:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Discount->add($this->request->data, $this->User->getLastInsertID());
}
```

Than using the uses variable:

```
public $uses = array('Users.User','AnotherPlugin.Discount');
```

However when I try to save the user, I get an auth violation when trying to call the add method on the Discount model.

Comment: What is the exact message? Are you sure the Discount model is actually loaded? Try to debug; `debug(get_class($this->Discount));`. Also; does the `Discount` model *have* a `add()` method and is it 'public'?

Comment: Yes the discount method has the method, it works calling it from the same plugin controller. I'm getting a: Security Error
The requested address was not found on this server.

Request blackholed due to "auth" violation. And if I take the $this->Discount->add out everything works fine.

Comment: If I debug(get_class($this->Discount)); I get 'Discount'

Comment: What exactly is inside the add() method?

Comment: Just saving a Discount model with some of the passed in data and returning true or false.

Comment: But `Discount` *is* a model, or is it a *Controller*?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29783/discussion-between-michael-and-thajeztah)